# MYSQL table column contraint based upon another tables columns

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my first post and I'm a mysql noob, so I apologize for this question's length.

BACKGROUND

I have a lookup table `cctypevals`, with a foreign field 'cctypeID', in mysql this would be:

```
CREATE TABLE `cctypevals` (
`cctypevalsKEY`  integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY , 
`cctypeID`  varchar(50) NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(cctypeID) REFERENCES cctype(cctypeID) , 
`value`  varchar(50)  )
```

`cctypeID` contains field names from user tables, eg 'taskSTATE', 'serviceTYPE', 'projectCAT' etc.

The value field contains the only allowed values for these user table fields.

Thus `cctypevals` acts like a 'multi' keyed lookup table, for example:

select value from cctypevals where cctypeID ='serviceTYPE'

might return HomeVisit, BackToBase etc

I know it would be easier to have one lookup table per field but this is what I have.

QUESTION

How do I constrain (in a sql create table or alter statement), tables with fields like task.taskSTATE, service.serviceTYPE etc so they can only accept values from `cctypevals`.`value` where  `cctypeID` contains the appropriate field name ?

Answer (score 1):

In create or alter table statement you cannot do that, since the `check` constraint would be able to such things, but mysql has not implemented the `check` constraint yet (mysql can parse a check constraint, but it will not work).

You can create before insert and update triggers that check the specific restrictions and [raise an sql error message](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/signal.html) if the updated value does not meet the requirements.

Comment: Thanks for that. So in a trigger I would run a select and check if the value was in it ? Do you think the only other way to this is to break out the current lookup table into separate tables ?

Comment: Or to use enums or sets, but those defeat the whole purpose of foreign keys. So, yes, either use triggers or have a separate lookup table for each lookup type.

Comment: Thanks again - I'll look into this.